# Let p be prime. If a group has more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$, why can't the group be cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $p$ be prime. If a group has more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$, why can't the group be cyclic?

Can I assume that the group must be finite group since there is at least one element with finite order?

And I am wondering now if all cyclic groups are finite, or all finite groups are cyclic?

Comment: Answer to the last question : No, not all finite groups are cyclic. And $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is cyclic, but not finite.

Comment: Also, not all cyclic groups are finite: $\mathbb{Z} = \langle 1 \rangle$

Comment: All finite groups are not cylic . For example $\Bbb Z_4, D_8, ...$. All cylic groups are not finite.For example $\Bbb Z=\langle 1\rangle$.

Comment: $\mathbb Z_4$ however is cyclic.

Comment: Hint. Look at the subgroup generated by an element of order $p$. (The integers under addition are an infinite cyclic group. The six element group of symmetries of a triangle isn't cyclic.)

Comment: @Peter, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

An infinite cyclic group has no elements of finite order, except for $e$, which has order $1$. Thus, your group cannot be infinite cyclic.

A finite cyclic group of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for each $d$ dividing $n$.

A subgroup of order $p$ in any group has exactly $p-1$ elements of order $p$.

Therefore, if a group has more than $p-1$ elements of order $p$, then it has more than one subgroup of order $p$ and so cannot be cyclic.

Comment: "A subgroup of order p
 in any group has exactly $p−1$
 elements of order $p$
." Is this because an element of the order must divide the order of its group? And since the group's order is prime, we can't find the element with the order other than 1 or $p$. The element of order 1 must be identity, so we are left with $p-1$ many elements who must have order $p$?

Comment: @user3000482, exactly